# Change directory where path in dictionary

Tags: powershell

I want to have part of a path in a dictionary, then change the path to that part that is in the dictionary plus another path part.  So for example:

```
$myparams=@{'part1'='c:\'}
cd $myparams['part1']\abc
```

I will get an error that says

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ...
```

However, this works for me:

```
$mydir = 'c:\'
cd $mydir\abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that Join-Path is a safer option than string concatenation:

```
cd (Join-Path $myparams['part1'] "abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd ($myparams['part1'] + "\abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place `$myparams['part1']` in a [sub-expression `$(...)`](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html):

```powershell
cd "$($myparams['part1'])\abc"
```

Note too that PowerShell hashtables allow you to access their values as if they were attributes:

```powershell
cd "$($myparams.part1)\abc"
```